# Referencing the same trait in another trait and class

Tags: php, traits

PHP seems to be trying to compile the same trait twice.

```
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkDictionary;
class FeatureContext
{
    use MinkDictionary, OrderDictionary;
}

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkDictionary;
trait OrderDictionary
{
    //if you comment out this line, everything works, but methodFromMinkTrait is
    //unresolved
    use MinkDictionary;

    public function myMethod($element, $text)
    {  
       //some method that uses methods from MinkDictionary
       return $this->methodFromMinkTrait();
    }
}
```

The compilation fails with a *Fatal Error*:

> Fatal error: Trait method setMink has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on LunchTime\DeliveryBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext
>
> `setMink` method is only defined in `MinkDictionary` trait.

The problem is that both `OrderDictionary` and `FeatureContext` are using methods from `MinkDictionary`. That's why I added `use MinkDictionary` in `OrderDictionary`. Is this not allowed? If you comment that out, then everything works, but the editor is showing a lot of unresolved methods - it doesn't know where they are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

of course it compiles the same trait twice, because you "use" MinkDictionary twice in class FeatureContext - first in the class itself and second via OrderDictionary.

just remove the "use MinkDictionary" statement from the FeatureContext class

Comment: all you ever wanted to know about traits is here: http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/11/trait-in-php/